# Debugging program that catches SIGKILL under Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, gdb

I have written small C++ program under Linux that uses AVX instructions. But the program receives `SIGKILL` signal and exits. It seems that the reason is some illegal instruction or wrong value passed to an instruction. I would need to learn at what point of the program it receives `SIGKILL` (at what instruction at best). But, when I run my program in GDB, program exits at the moment when it receives `SIGKILL`and cannot be debugged. I tried to set:

```
    (gdb) handle SIGKILL stop print nopass
```

but program still receives SIGKILL and exits before I can debug it. Do you have any tip how to work with this?

Comment: You *can't* catch the `SIGKILL` signal. See e.g. [`man 7 signal`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

Comment: As for your problem, you should first of all build with extra warnings enabled (at least use the `-Wall` flag to GCC, I also recommend `-Wextra` and `-pedantic`). This should hopefully give you hints on places where you might have [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Then run in a system such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), even if it doesn't catch just your problem, it might give you more information about weird things you do with memory and pointers.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Or use the -fsanitize options, such as 'address' and 'undefined'.

Comment: Are you sure that an illegal machine instruction is sending exactly `SIGKILL`? According to [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) it should be `SIGILL` -without any `K` .... !!

Answer (score 0):

The [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) man page tells that on illegal machine instruction (or [illegal opcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illegal_opcode)), the

> ```
>    SIGILL        4       Core    Illegal Instruction
> ```

signal is sent. Notice that it is `SIGILL` *not* `SIGKILL` (the letter `K` makes a big difference).

Recall that not every processor know about [AVX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions). (On those that don't support AVX, it probably is an illegal opcode). Type `cat /proc/cpuinfo` (or `grep avx /proc/cpuinfo`) to know if your's processor accepts it. See [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

<sup>So I guess that your program is getting the `SIGILL` (*not* `SIGKILL`) signal.</sup>

You can catch `SIGILL` (but you *cannot* catch `SIGKILL`).

What I explained in [this answer (about `SIGSEGV`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25305692/841108) is applicable to `SIGILL`; with some very *tricky machine and system specific C code*, you might *catch `SIGILL`* and ensure that upon return from the signal handler (installed with `SA_SIGINFO` and deeply processing the `ucontext_t*` third argument) the execution continues outside of the illegal instructions.

And you could configure `gdb` to handle `SIGILL` wisely. Read the [signals chapter](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Signals.html) of GDB documentation, you probably want the `handle SIGILL` and/or `p $_siginfo`  command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I really got SIGKILL with K. Code can be found in: https://github.com/hagrid-the-developer/Turgnaimh/blob/master/AVX/matrix.cpp . Under Mac Os X, it runs OK, under Linux, AVX part runs OK, but float part (matrix_mul_8x8_slow) receives SIGKILL. Float part without AVX part runs OK too. It looks to me like AVX part sets some CPU flag that confuses float part. I tried to supply additional warning flags to compiler, but it wrote only: `warning: ISO C++ does not support the ‘%m’ gnu_printf format [-Wformat]`.