# What's the status of the MADV_USERFAULT flag in madvise()?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, paging

There have been some discussions to use a new flag in madvise() to tell the kernel not to handle page faults in certain memory ranges: [lwn.net-1](https://lwn.net/Articles/615086/), [lwn.net-2](https://lwn.net/Articles/549503/)

As far as I am able to see, this flag hasn't found its way to the kernel source.

**What's the current status of this work?**

Comment: Don't know exactly, but see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25305692/841108) to a perhaps related question

Comment: Thanks for the pointer (even though it does not fully answer the question). I think I will try running this patch and see how it goes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The community never went forward with MADV_USERFAULT.  Instead, a more robust solution called userfaultfd has made its way into the kernel.
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/userfaultfd.txt